# A mounted directory on a container with label type container_file_t can be accessed by a process running in a different domain (user_t)

Tags: podman, selinux

I was running some tests to see how effective SELinux is in containerized environments,and I came upon an irregular behavior, and I can't understand why it's happening.
Let's say in the case where someone managed to give the wrong permissions to a mounted directory (rwxrwxrwx) on a container, in my case I'm using Podman, this would mean that in a system where only DAC checks are performed, anyone can access and modify this directory, but if SELinux was enabled and running in enforcing mode, and the directory was correctly labeled with the "container_file_t" context associated with containers, this would mean that even if the DAC allows access, the SELinux would allow only processes running in the appropriate domain (container_t) to have access to it. But in my case, SELinux doesn't block the access

So here's how I recreated this test

1. First thing I changed Selinux mode to enforcing
2. I created a home directory /home/TestDir
3. Then I chmod 777 /home/TestDir so that all users (different SELinux profiles) can access this directory
4. Created a container (in root mode), and bind mounted the created directory with the SELinux flag :Z

```
`podman run -dit -v /home/TestDir:/data:Z registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8`
```

5. The /home/TestDir directory got the appropriate Selinux type : `system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c236,c488`
6. Logged with SSH to another user JohnDoe. It is associated with a user_u SELinux user : `user_u:user_r:user_t:s0`
7. The processes initiated with this user are all running in the user_t domain
8. I accessed the /home/TestDir and created a test file ==> It worked !! No error was generated
9. No error logged in journalctl ou audit.log

Now it seems that even though I'm running SELinux in enforcing mode, a home directory ( That i chmod to 777 purposely ) with a label type container_file_t can be accessed with processes running in different domains with no problem. So it seems as if the MAC control in this case is as permissive as the DAC.

My question is did I miss something in the SELinux configuration when running Podman, or is this a normal behavior and there's a logical explanation for it ?

Thanks in advance !!